# Microsoft Bot Framework Async Suggested Actions Not Working

Tags: botframework

I'm trying to incorporate suggested actions into my bot

In this case the suggestions come from an API

I am using async/await to add the suggestions in

However the bot does not render them even though the suggestedActions field is set in the action payload.

Everything works if the suggested actions are hardcoded, but not when they are retrieved using async/await

Here is the piece of code with async / await that does not work.

```
const store = window.WebChat.createStore({}, function(store) { return function(next) { return async function(action) {
        if (action.type === 'DIRECT_LINE/CONNECT_FULFILLED') {
            store.dispatch({
                type: 'DIRECT_LINE/POST_ACTIVITY',
                meta: {method: 'keyboard'},
                payload: {
                    activity: {
                        type: "invoke",
                        name: "InitConversation",
                        locale: user.locale,
                        value: {
                            // must use for authenticated conversation.
                            jsonWebToken: jsonWebToken,

                            // Use the following activity to proactively invoke a bot scenario
                            /*
                            triggeredScenario: {
                                trigger: "{scenario_id}",
                                args: {
                                    location: location,
                                    myVar1: "{custom_arg_1}",
                                    myVar2: "{custom_arg_2}"
                                }
                            }
                            */
                        }
                    }
                }
            });

        }
        else if (action.type === 'DIRECT_LINE/INCOMING_ACTIVITY') {
            if(action.payload.activity.from.role == 'bot' && action.payload.activity.type == 'message' && !action.payload.activity.text.startsWith("##") && !action.payload.activity.text.startsWith("You are now connected")){
                console.log(action)
                sa = {
                    "actions": [
                        {
                            "type": "imBack",
                            "title": "Bluee",
                            "value": "Blue"
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "imBack",
                            "title": "Reed",
                            "value": "Red"
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "imBack",
                            "title": "Green",
                            "value": "Green"
                        }
                    ]
                }

                const dataToSend = {
                    message: action.payload.activity.text,
                }
        
               const fetchRes = await fetch("/incomingMessage", {
                    method: "POST",
                    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}, 
                    body: JSON.stringify(dataToSend)
                });
                const textRes = await fetchRes.text();
                sa.actions[0].title = textRes;
                action.payload.activity.suggestedActions = sa;
            }
    ...
    return next(action);
}}});
```

Here is the changed snippet (showing removal of the async/await pattern and hardcoded suggestions that displays hardcoded suggestions correctly

```
else if (action.type === 'DIRECT_LINE/INCOMING_ACTIVITY') {
            if(action.payload.activity.from.role == 'bot' && action.payload.activity.type == 'message' && !action.payload.activity.text.startsWith("##") && !action.payload.activity.text.startsWith("You are now connected")){
                console.log(action)
                sa = {
                    "actions": [
                        {
                            "type": "imBack",
                            "title": "Bluee",
                            "value": "Blue"
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "imBack",
                            "title": "Reed",
                            "value": "Red"
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "imBack",
                            "title": "Green",
                            "value": "Green"
                        }
                    ]
                }
        
                action.payload.activity.suggestedActions = sa;}
```